# Why don't they use balloons in ocean as battery?

Tags: climate-change, geoengineering

We need more batteries, to store renewable. But why don't they just pull down big balloons in the ocean and let them go up when they need the power?

Comment: This is a good idea, but I suspect that it's far more expensive and technologically challenging than using other gravity powered storage devices. You can achieve a similar effect by using weights, pumped storage HEP, or even railway cars on an incline.

Comment: I kindly ask to be a bit more specific, which effect you're talking off, a few details about the hows, wheres, transport of electrical(?) energy, and the question will probably pop like a balloon.

Comment: Well, I'm taking about the pressure effect, if you pull a balloon with air down into water it want to go up. If you pull a wire with that balloon you can create spinning and spinning is electric. But why don't we use it?

Comment: @Will I am not so sure in that. These underwater balloons could start from nearly any depth. For example, they can be started from 3km deep sea. To build a 3km high tower, capable to support a huge mass of water, is practically impossible.

Comment: @FredrikKristiansen: Because energy conversion and transport is "a bit" more complicated, not even talking about effectiveness. Voting to close because it's not earth science but engineering and anyway needs a lot of specification.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you. You transport electric energy with an electric wire? When you turn of the brake that stop the balloon from going up. It spins a elektro magnet that makes energy. Nothing more to it.

Comment: It kind of exists in a different way: the StEnSea project (see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_Energy_at_Sea, and this paper for more science: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.est.2017.06.004). The sphere is anchored at depth, the water is let in to create electricity or pumped out at off-peak hours, like classic PHES systems in mountainous areas.

Comment: The answer is probably "because it's terribly inefficient and few people need energy at sea". But engineers could answer this more ... efficiently. @FredrikKristiansen: even a cable has losses and over those distances they would be remarkable. And all the conversion electrical/transformation/transport - mechanical - gravitational/potential - and back again would leave the contraption with little use.

Comment: @a_donda Most cities are close to water.

Comment: @FredrikKristiansen wellcome to earth science,your idea is good and gravity has been harvested in producing power for a long time but there might be better ways to harvest energy than by using the bouyancy of gass in water.

Comment: If you were merely cranking an ideal buoyant sphere to depth and letting it rise, you might have something there, but once you put something in the ocean you have to start dealing with biofouling and corrosion and once you start putting things at depth you have to start dealing with several atmospheres of compression and decompression -- you'd need a very flexible fabric that's also leak-proof for hundreds of cycles.

Comment: The answer to why "they" don't do it is obviously that none of "them" have wanted to devote the necessary capital to designing and building such a system.  So you just need to form a company, attract a bunch of venture capital, and hire some good engineers :-)